# Do I have to make a new project with lower swift and xcode for el capitan below MacOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I made a app using Xcode 11.3 and Swift 5. It works perfectly with MacOS siera and above but does not work in el capitan and yosemite. The form just shows a webview page.

The form shows just for a second and closes by itself. Does any one know the cause for this?

This is the code to show the window when a button pressed.

```
 func ShowWindow(_ form_name:String) -> NSWindow?{

    let storyboard: NSStoryboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: form_name) as? NSWindowController
    if windowController == nil {
        return nil
    }

    let window:NSWindow = windowController!.window!
    window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
    window.center()
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    return window
}

ShowSingleWindow("LoginForm")
```

And the view controller connected to LoginForm is LoginFormVC
and inside the code is

```
var m_webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    UserInfo.shared.SetLogs("LoginForm Display")

    m_webView = WKWebView()
    m_webView.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.addSubview(m_webView)
    m_webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "scriptHandler")
    m_webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    m_webView.uiDelegate = self
    m_webView.navigationDelegate = self

    let infoPlistDict = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
    let handlerUrl = infoPlistDict["handlerUrl"] as! String;
    let url = URL(string: "\(handlerUrl)/agent_login.aspx")!
    m_webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

Comment: Do you keep a strong reference to the window controller or window? See [AppKit Release Notes for macOS 10.13](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/), NSWindow Lifecycle Changes. "If your application is linked on macOS 10.13 SDK or later, NSWindows that are ordered-in will be strongly referenced by AppKit, until they are explicitly ordered-out or closed (not including hide or minimize operations). This means that, generally, an on-screen window will not be deallocated (and close/order-out as a side-effect of deallocation)."

Comment: As already mentioned by @Willeke just move your window declaration out of your ShowWindow method. `let window:NSWindow = windowController!.window!`. Btw It is Swift naming convention to name your methods starting with a lowercase letter `func showWindow(` and don't use underscore between words, use camel case `formName`

Comment: I just started with swift developing. I still dont get what to do.. can you guys explain alittle bit more?